# Can't get UITouch event from UIButton

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, user-interface

Problem:

I can't get my UIButton to send my Class an Event call

Here is what I tried first:

I made a class which extends UIViewController, called Viewer

```
#import "Viewer.h"
#import "MainScreen.h"

@implementation Viewer

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    MainScreen* main = [[MainScreen alloc]init: self];
    [main show];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

then:

- I created a class called MainScreen, 2 IBOutlets - singlePlayerButton and view
- Viewer is an instance of UIViewController
- buttonPressed has the return type of IBAction

MainScreen:

```
#import "MainScreen.h"
#import "Viewer.h"

@implementation MainScreen
{
    IBOutlet UIButton* singlePlayerButton;
    IBOutlet UIView* view;

    Viewer* viewer;
}

- (id)init:(Viewer*) theViewer
{
    self = [super init];
    viewer = theViewer;
    return self;
}

- (void)show
{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MainScreenLayout" owner:self options:nil];
    [viewer.view addSubview:view];
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"A button was pressed!");
}

@end
```

Then I created an NIB called `MainScreenLayout.xib`

Here is what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot of my NIB file]

As you can see, I have four buttons but the only one that is connected to anything is the Single-Player button I also have the UIView connected to view.

Now, I linked the action to the Single-Player button like this:

[image: Screenshot of connecting the action to the button]

`buttonPressed` is my method that I want to have called when the button is pressed, so I ctrl-clicked on First Responder and then clicked on the circle next to `buttonPressed` and then dragged it on top of the Single-Player button. Then the next dialog window popped up and I clicked on Touch up Inside. Here is what the Received Actions window looks like:

[image: Screenshot of First Responder Window]

Now, I thought at this point it should work. I ran it on my iPhone Simulator and pressed the button.

Just so there is no question of whither or not I'm competent, here is a picture of me actually clicking the button:

[image: Screenshot]

I got no output whatsoever. Then I went to my code and looked at the method. This is what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot of method]

as you can see, the oval is not filled, meaning that the method is not paired. So naturally I thought it was being overridden by another method. So here is what the method looks like now:

```
- (IBAction)aVerySpecificMethodNameForMyButtonListener:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"A button was pressed!");
}
```

Then I went back to my NIB window, unpaired my Single-Player button and then repaired it to `aVerySpecificMethodNameForMyButtonListener`. Now this is what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot for rediculous method name]

Then I ran it again and still nothing when I pressed the button. Then I went back to the code:

[image: Screen shot]

(insert frustration here)

At this point I restarted Xcode and the Simulator and looked over everything again and it still didn't work.

This is what I tried next which seems about a billion times more simple:

```
- (void)show
{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MainScreenLayout" owner:self options:nil];
    [viewer.view addSubview:view];

    [singlePlayerButton addTarget:self action:@selector(aVerySpecificMethodNameForMyButtonListener:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

I replaced with my `show` method with the one above. The only thing different is the last line. I disconnected my method from the Single-Player button in the NIB. Then I ran it and I got excited for a second because I got some output. Here is what I got:

```
(lldb)
```

Very helpful output C debugger, as always. I spent the next few hours on SO trying to find out what I'm doing wrong. I've tried countless examples and none of them worked.

Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong here? Is it just Xcode being flakey?

Thanks for reading!! All relevant answers are welcomed!

---

UPDATE:

I also tried changing the declaration of UIButton to a property in the Header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Viewer.h"

@interface MainScreen : NSObject
{
    IBOutlet UIView* view;

    Viewer* viewer;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton* singlePlayerButton;

- (id)init:(Viewer*) theViewer;
- (void)show;
- (IBAction)aVerySpecificMethodNameForMyButtonListener:(id)sender;

@end
```

Thus here is what I changed in MainScreen.m to comply:

```
#import "MainScreen.h"
#import "Viewer.h"

@implementation MainScreen

- (id)init:(Viewer*) theViewer
{
    self = [super init];
    viewer = theViewer;
    return self;
}

@synthesize singlePlayerButton;

- (void)show
{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MainScreenLayout" owner:self options:nil];
    [viewer.view addSubview:view];

    [singlePlayerButton addTarget:self action:@selector(aVerySpecificMethodNameForMyButtonListener:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (IBAction)aVerySpecificMethodNameForMyButtonListener:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"A button was pressed!");
}

@end
```

Now there are no variable declarations inside of the MainScreen.m file, I moved them all to the Header. The circles next to `singlePlayerButton` and `view` are still filled in but the bubble next to the method is not. I ran the code again and got the same output.

Comment: in your last attempt to get this working, did you declare the `UIButton` property in your header file?  Should be something like `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *singlePlayerButton;`.  You will also need to connect the button to this declaration (circle next to it filled in).  Then to hook up the action, will need to reference the button as `self.singlePlayerButton addTarget...`

Comment: @bobnoble the bubble next to `singlePlayerButton` and `view` are both filled. The button next to my method is not filled in. Right now I just have the UIButton defined inside of the braces of the Implementation of `MainScreen`. I'll add it as a property and then I'll update my post. Good Idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'd have put this in a comment because its really just a suggestion however I dont have the rep yet so sorry to get your hopes up, but I believe the touch event's scope is only inside the UIView in which it happens. When the touch up event gets triggered it doesn't get passed to the UIView's handler (MainScreen class) and so the event's listener method does not get called... but that you are able to link it in the interface builder to the button is baffling to me, so i could be way off.

Anyways, where I think you should go next is to make your MainScreen a UIView object and see what that does for event handling of the buttons in the view.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm going to restructure my program and see how it works out. Hopefully it works!